# EF6 code first and VIEW

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to add a VIEW to the database, and query the data from this VIEW using L2E. I use migrations for maintaining database schema.

I added one class that should MAP to a VIEW columns. As an example, this class has only two properties

```
[Table("View_Data")]
public class ViewData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class ViewDataMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ViewData>
{
    public ViewDataMap ()
    {
        this.ToTable("View_Data");
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

I added ViewDataMap to OnModelCreating, as with any other Table mappings. I added DbSet ViewDatas.

When I executed

```
add-migration preview
```

it created new migration with CreateTable command. Since I do not want to create a table, but only a view, I replaced in UP() CreateTable with Sql("CREATE VIEW...")

Still, EF complains about pending changes in database, and still wants to create new migration with CreateTable()...

How can prevent EF to create new table, but use VIEW instead?

Comment: That is how we do it. You did an `update-database`? Once you do that EF takes a snapshot so on the next migrations only new items and changes would be included. You can troubleshoot by scripting everything out and see what EF is trying to do `update-database -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase -Script`

Comment: @SteveGreene Yep, that was it. :-) Post your message as an answer.

Comment: You had most of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve suggested in the comment, I forgot to do **update-database**, then all works as expected.